# How to reload in CRON job? (sending GET value on reload)

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I am using this command to do CRON Job from Cpanel

```
wget http://example.com.com/test.php
```

I have this Javascript code inside the PHP file, which reload the page.

```
echo'<script> location.replace("?number='.$requestsDone.'"); </script>';
```

Now you may say, Just do the CRON job every minute. But, i guess, it will not do what I want, in my case.

As you can see, i am sending a `GET` value, when i reload the page. And that `GET` value is important part of my code.

So, I tried to run that page with that command (given above), but it do not reload the page (that Javascript code do not work).

So, what's the solution?

Let me know, if you did not understand.

Comment: You're doing a `wget`; what does "reload the page" even mean in that context? Nothing you posted indicates that the JavaScript code will even run.

Comment: wget doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: ohh, what command should i use to execute Javascript?

Comment: You'd need some kind of browser, headless or otherwise.  I don't recommend it.  Your cron php should be written to do the task without needing to load a different url, like figure out $requestsDone and then include whatever php code consumes it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will only work in a browser. You can use [phantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) and use it like cron if you would like to run javascript but it will be little complicated.

so you can just use curl in php to achieve your purpose of reloading page like this:

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}


$output = curl_download("http://www.example.com/yourscript.php?number='$requestsDone'");
```

Comment: I just copy/paste the whole code? Or i need to edit it? It do nothing in browser, it will work in cron job?

Comment: Yes copy paste whole function. And then call it when you want to refresh the page with url and query parameters. Ie: place `curl_download($url)`  instead of `echo script`.

Comment: and it's same as running another cron job so your php script will run again with query parameters you include in url in function argument.

Comment: i placed this at the end of the code `curl_download($Url);` and got this error `Notice: Undefined variable: Url` What is wrong? This is how we call function right bro?

Comment: and what is the use of example.com/yhy.htm here?

Comment: you can set it to your current url or you can just remove it. It sets HTTP referrer for the request.